# Running Internal OS on Virtual Box

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, multi-boot, dualboot

I am Using dual boot OS in my laptop, which is Windows 10 and PopOS (Linux).
I am installing virtualbox on Windows, and I wonder, if there's a way to Run Other OS in same hard disk and same time when I am running Other OS with VirtualBox?

**Example** : I want to run Linux when I'm running Windows with VirtualBox.
So I can run my other OS without shutting down my laptop.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/545303/chaining-bootloaders-for-unusual-setup) for details on the setup I used and parts that I didn't like about it. Also the Virtualbox manual for [using raw disks](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chaining bootloaders for unusual setup](https://superuser.com/questions/545303/chaining-bootloaders-for-unusual-setup)

Answer (score -1):

**No, it's not possible to use VirtualBox to run a non-virtual machine installed in your computer**. If you want to run a Linux OS while using Windows, create a new Linux virtual machine with Virtualbox!

Comment: You have misunderstood the question.  It is possible to run Linux in the VM while running Windows natively, without shutting down the PC.

Comment: To be fair, the question is poorly or awkwardly worded. This is one way I understood the question as well. OP needs to edit the question to make it more clear, not just add EDITed alternate lines which so far make it more confusing.